# Display attribute by atribute id not on product page in magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I am trying to show the attribute with html by attribute id in magento...the thing to note is that I don't have to show it on product page but on the phtml of the custom module.....Please help me out as I have spent near about 8 hours and it is important for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
$attributes = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
        ->getAttributeCollection()
        ->addSetInfo();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute->usesSource())
    {
        echo "{$attribute->getFrontendLabel()}:\n";
        foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions() as $option)
        {
            echo "  {$option['label']}\n";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Or try below code

```
$attributeModel = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
```

Where `$attributecode` is attribute code e.g. color,manufacture.

For further info you can refer this [Link](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-attribute-name-and-value/)

Comment: What are you getting in collection?